# Pattern matching and their counts in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following values in a column A. I would need to write a query for all existences of particular pattern and display the counts for that pattern. Could you please help on how to write this in SQL server.

```
Column A
-------------------------------------
abc.(Backbridge)
bac.(Not Required)
abxsa.<sb not available in ont>.sbb
kcr.<sb not available in ont>.tdp
hikh.<sb not available in ont>.nji
sac.(Not Required)

Column B                Counts
-------------------------------
Backbridge                 1 
Not required               2
sb not available in ont    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement in a `COUNT` like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN column_a LIKE '%Backbridge%' THEN 1 END) AS Backbridge_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN column_a LIKE '%Not required %' THEN 1 END) AS Not required_count     
    COUNT(CASE WHEN column_a LIKE '%sb not available in ont%' THEN 1 END) AS sb_not_avilable_in_ont_count     
FROM 
    <my_table>;
```

...or this for something like you asked for:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN column_a LIKE '%Backbridge%' THEN 'Backbridge'
        WHEN column_a LIKE '%Not required%' THEN 'Not required'
        WHEN column_a LIKE '%sb not available in ont%' THEN 'sb not available in ont'
        ELSE 'Not matched'
    END AS match_name,
    COUNT(1) AS count_value
FROM 
    <my_table>
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN column_a LIKE '%Backbridge%' THEN 'Backbridge'
        WHEN column_a LIKE '%Not required%' THEN 'Not required'
        WHEN column_a LIKE '%sb not available in ont%' THEN 'sb not available in ont'
    END;
```

Comment: thanks Richard. This query is giving me only count. How can I get the Pattern matching string in another column as well?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the results for three counts. I guess the next question is what you want to do with them? This is fine for reporting, but if you want to use these values to update another table (for example) then that can get challenging as there's rules about using aggregates for `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: thanks Richard. this is for reporting purpose only.